# Inserting into mysql table using foreign key with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I have two tables,

users_table and orders table.

users_id is in both tables

as a primary key in users_table and as foreign key in orders_table(referencing users_id in users_table)

When I try to place an order if it's the first time the user is able to place an order but if a user already placed an order the data is not saved to the database in the second attempt.. any Idea why? or any solutions?

I apologise for the bad english

MY PHP CODE:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orders_table(users_id, orders_postDate, orders_category, orders_categoryId, orders_name, orders_description, orders_deliveryDate) VALUES('$users_id', '$orders_postDate', '$orders_category', '$orders_categoryId', '$orders_name', '$orders_description', '$orders_deliveryDate')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if($result){
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }else{
        echo "fail";
    }
```

so Let's say that I created an account, signed in and placed an order, the data is successfully on the database. if I try to place a new order with the same user I get the fail message.. so for some reason

```
mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

fails the second time, I am assuming that it is because my foreign key is a primary key? how can I fix this?

Comment: Post your code...done

Comment: What have you tried already? Show us some code. See how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you Jamie. I will be more careful

Comment: `echo "fail";` doesn't help you. This does: Add `or die(mysqli_error($connection));` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Why are you having some backticks on your query?done

Comment: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in /Applications/XAMPP/.....Functions.php on line 136

Comment: what do you mean by backticks?

Comment: Fixed it, I accidentally put those by pressing ctrl + k after copy paste..

Comment: That error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string` is not caused by what you posted for code. One reason could be that you are using `mysql_` to connect with, then using `mysqli_` to query. If that is the case, you can't mix those different MySQL APIs. You need to use the same from connecting to querying. Or, there's an error in your connection method. You need to add it to your question. Or, there's something else you didn't show us, like using SELECT to echo your query.

Comment: Fred my code works, but the problem is the second time I try to place an order.. it does not work, I see the fail message so $result fails. it is because of the foreign key, because when I remove the foreign key it works.. what I would like to know is how to fix it so that it works with the foreign key..

users_id in users_table is a primary key and I have users_id in orders_table   this is not a primary key but a foreign key so maybe it automatically becomes a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, if `orders_table.user_id` with primary key, also there is a '`unique`' key. If so, MySql did not allow to paste the same `user_id`.

Use `ALTER TABLE` sql command to remove the primary key on  `orders_table.user_id` add add a new column with primary key.

There is code you need:

```
ALTER TABLE orders_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE orders_table ADD COLUMN `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE orders_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

Comment: I do now know how to show SQL dump, what I did is created users_id in orders_table, press index button, than I linked it to the users_id which is a primary key in the users_table. If I dont do these steps my code works, but when I do it like this, it does not work on the second time

Answer (score 0):

Without code/error message it is difficult to say what the issue is. However, you mentioned that `user_id` is the foreign key for the `orders_table`, but if it is also used for the primary key for your `orders_table` it would cause duplication when creating any subsequent orders, hence, insertion of a new order would fail.

These might help you to help us to get a better understanding of whats going on.

- How is your `orders_table` created?
- What is the primary key for `Orders_table`?
- How do you assign the primary key (if you do) upon insertion of a new record?
- Since you are able to insert the first record that means you get a successful connection. So instead of echoing "success" and "fail", extract the [mysqli error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead.

Also, since you are dealing with MySQL and PHP you might want to take a look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) objects instead, if you haven't already. Being able to use prepared statements is a huge plus.

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is not getting data from the users_table and so will not be able to insert the right user data into the Orders_table; and second, the order_table is created having user_id as a primary key and foreign key which will cause data duplication. Try altering the table to drop the primary and create another column for it(Primary key).

An example

```
ALTER TABLE orders_table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE orders_table ADD COLUMN 'id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

That should make your code work now.